curl not able to read or write cookies from files created by mktemp command
I'm working on a bash script that requires capturing cookies from web requests.
What I'm Trying to Achieve

Create a temporary file using mktemp
Use curl to make a web request
Capture all cookies set by the server in this temporary file
Be able to read and use these cookies in subsequent requests

My Current Approach which is working
COOKIE_FILE=~/cookies.txt
curl https://example.com -c "$COOKIE_FILE" -b "$COOKIE_FILE"

Temporary file approach (fails)
COOKIE_FILE=$(mktemp)
curl https://example.com -c "$COOKIE_FILE" -b "$COOKIE_FILE"

and
COOKIE_FILE=$(tempfile --mode=666)
curl https://example.com -c "$COOKIE_FILE" -b "$COOKIE_FILE"

Environment

vagrantbox - ubuntu/focal64  (virtualbox, 20240821.0.1)
Linux ubuntu-focal 5.4.0-193-generic #213-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 2 19:14:16 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
curl version
 curl 8.1.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/8.1.2 OpenSSL/1.1.1f zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 zstd/1.4.4 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.40.0 librtmp/2.3 libgsasl/1.8.1
 Release-Date: 2023-05-30
 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
 Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli gsasl GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd


to install this version of curl I followed these steps.
sudo apt purge curl
sudo apt autoremove
sudo snap install curl




Possibly relevant Snap apps don't find files in /tmp/

Isn't there a way to use /tmp directory for applications installed from snap?
